# VBA - A document with the name '' is already open

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro in Excel that I assigned to a button in a workbook. When pressed it asks a user for a file, opens that file and copies the contents into the sheet2 in the original workbook, then saves the original workbook under a new name. It then creates a new button on the worksheet to run another subroutine. When pressing the button a window pops up saying "A document with the name (document name) is already open. Is there anyway to resolve this? I assume this is happening because I'm saving the original workbook under a new name.

```
Sub openFile()

Dim tempWB As Object, btn As Button, desktopPath As String

fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select transaction history export:")
If fileToOpen <> False Then
    Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fileToOpen)
End If
If fileToOpen = False Then
    End
End If

ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
tempWB.Close

Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(650, 50, 100, 40)
With btn
    .OnAction = "action"
End With

desktopPath = (MacScript("(path to desktop from user domain as string)") & ":")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(desktopPath & "Result" & VBA.format(Date, "mm/dd/yy") & ".xlsm")

End Sub

Sub action()

Range("A1:B1").Font.Size = 14

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through and watched the value that NAMES the new file?

Comment: I would suggest changing `tempWB.Close` to `tempWB.Close: Set tempWB = Nothing`. That should release the variable's link to the window handle.